# error installing library in python, i have held broken packets

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install an exp17 on raspberry pi. For this, I need the library in python eyes17, but I am not successful when installing it. The error is as follows:

```
sudo apt install eyes17

Reading package list... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading status information... Done
Do not can instal some pack. This may mean that
you asked for an impossible situation or, if you are using the distribution
unstable, that some required packages have not yet been created or are
have taken from «Incoming».
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 eyes17 : Depends: python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine but not installable

          Recommends: fonts-lohit-mlym but it won't install
          Recommends: libreoffice but it won't install
E: The problems could not be corrected, you have held broken packets.
```

Comment: Please don't (machine-)translate error messages. "Do not can instal some pack." is not something apt ever outputs.